# Stored procedure is returning an empty value

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have created the following stored procedure:

OrderDetails - `Id(int), OrderId(int), AnniID(int), Quantity(int), UnitCost(money)`

Anniversary - `AnniID (int), Title( varchar(50) )`

AnniID will be the foreignKey to link up the 2 tables.

When I execute the stored procedure, it returns nothing despite it actually having 1 item in the database.

Is there any problem to the code? Or did I not inner join correctly?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Selectpurchasedwithproducts @AnniID INT
AS
    SELECT TOP 5 OrderDetails.AnniID,
                 Anniversary.Title,
                 Sum(OrderDetails.Quantity) AS TotalNum
    FROM   OrderDetails
           INNER JOIN Anniversary
             ON OrderDetails.AnniID = Anniversary.AnniID
    WHERE  OrderId IN (
                      /* This inner query should retrieve all orders that have contained the anniID */
                      SELECT DISTINCT OrderId
                       FROM   OrderDetails
                       WHERE  AnniID = @AnniID)
           AND OrderDetails.AnniID != @AnniID
    GROUP  BY OrderDetails.AnniID,
              Anniversary.Title
    ORDER  BY TotalNum DESC

    RETURN
```

Comment: Why you using **RETURN** at the end?? and also just try running the query with manually passing the @AnniID

Comment: when i execute the code, a window pop up and I manually key in the AnniID, but still returning nothing.

Comment: what is the result you need actually.. just innerjoin results..?

Comment: WHERE AnniID = AnniID
)
AND OrderDetails.AnniID != AnniID. Why do you write this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your statement to me

```
WHERE   OrderId IN  
(     
    /* This inner query should retrieve all orders
       that have contained the anniID   */
    SELECT DISTINCT OrderId      
        FROM OrderDetails     
        WHERE AnniID = @AnniID 
) 
AND OrderDetails.AnniID != @AnniID
```

How can OrderDetails that are equal to `@AnniID` not be equal to `@AnniID`?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is slightly confusing with how you have it written;

First, you have JOINed your two tables on the AnniId:

```
FROM   OrderDetails
INNER JOIN Anniversary
   ON OrderDetails.AnniID = Anniversary.AnniID
```

Second, you want the OrderIds from the OrderDetails table where the `AnniId = @AnniId`

```
WHERE OrderId IN 
(
   /* This inner query should retrieve all orders that have contained the anniID */
   SELECT DISTINCT OrderId 
   FROM OrderDetails
   WHERE AnniID = @AnniID
)
```

But then you want OrderDetails where the AnniID is not equal to @AnniId:

```
AND OrderDetails.AnniID != @AnniID
```

You have several conflicting statements in your query. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?